# AWS/S3/boto3: Can't use presigned_url to upload file to bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following code to get a presigned_url:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url=AWS_ENDPOINT)
presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                 Params={'Bucket': "my-bucket",
                                                         'Key':"my-key"},
                                                 ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

then I using the following command to upload the file

```
curl -v --upload-file my-key {presigned_url}
```

but I get `AccessDenied` error. Do I need to setup some permission on the S3 bucket? Do I need to assigned special permission when generating presigned_url under boto3?

Comment: Does the role / user you use to generate the presigned url have the proper permissions? Does the bucket have a bucket policy that might prevent the request?

Comment: You're generating a GET request presigned URL.  `--upload-file` uses PUT, so change your method from `get_object` to `put_object`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `get_object` for `put_object`

- [generate_presigned_url](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/generate_presigned_url.html): mainly used with `get_object`, but it could be used with `put_object`, `list_buckets` or `get_bucket_location`.
- Also you could use [generate_presigned_post](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/generate_presigned_post.html): create an url to upload a file.

Here you can see a working example: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file